# Merge java.util.date with java.sql.Time

Tags: java, sql, date, time, merge

I have an extensive DATE-TIME conversion class, but i came across a scenario that i cannot resolve:

I have a java.util.date: Tue May 10 00:00:00 BST 2011
I have a java.sql.time: 03:58:44

**I need to create a java.util.date: Tue May 10 03:58:44 BST 2011**

The only approach i came up with is:

```
public static Date getDate(Date date, Time time) {
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay(), time.getHours(), time.getMinutes(), time.getSeconds());
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Totally deprecated code, and does not work:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at java.sql.Time.getYear(Unknown Source)

Any ideas?

Comment: If you got that exception on that code, then you actually passed in a `Time` instance on the first parameter!

Comment: joda-time is always the best approach to work with dates in java http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: <rant>On a partially related note: While the `java.util.Date` API is very poorly constructed and should long ago have been replace with a sane one (such as [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)), the `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Time` "extension" is even worse: They **both** don't follow the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and to make matters worse `java.sql.Date` even has the same simple name as its base class.</rant>

Comment: I agree, i had to make an optimized conversion class that has everything i need and one that makes SENSE to me... java.util.date is a pain... but right now i just need a simple solution to this scenario.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

java.sql.Time is just a wrapper over the java.util.Date. You can use it as if you would add two java.util.Date objects.

For example, set Calendar to java.sql.Time:

```
calendar.setTime(time);
```

Now extract the hour/minute/seconds fields, i.e.:

```
calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

Next, set the Calendar to java.util.Date object and add these three fields to its time, i.e.:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
```

And get the Date back:

```
calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: Just a remark: we must use HOUR_OF_DAY to respect the 24 hour format.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way would be to just add the milli secs together to create a new date, ala

```
public static Date getDate(Date date, Time time) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + time.getTime())
}
```

Comment: Works, But i get one hour less... Tue May 10 00:00:00 BST 2011 &
03:58:44 = Tue May 10 02:58:44 BST 2011

Answer (score 4):

vickirk's solution wasn't so bad, but has timezone issues, which results in the one hour less you observed.

I suppose, BST means [British Summer Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time), which is GMT +0100. Now, java.util.Date and its descendants internally work with numbers of milliseconds since midnight Jan 01, 1970 **GMT**. The timezone is not taken into account until you stringfy the date/time with `toString()`. And they use your local timezone for that, which is BST, apparently. That means, what is really stored in these objects, is

java.util.date: Mon May **09 23**:00:00 **GMT** 2011
java.sql.time: **02**:58:44 **GMT**

When you add the internal values (which are retrieved by `getTime()`) like vickirk suggested, you obtain a date which contains
Tue May 10 **01**:58:44 **GMT** 2011, which then results in
Tue May 10 **02**:58:44 **BST** 2011 on stringification.

So the explanation for the one hour less is that the timezone offset applies twice, when you stringified the values separately, whereas it applies only once after the addition, because you stringfy only once now. Or, from another point of view, adding the internal value of the *point in time* 03:58:44 BST is equivalent to adding a *time span* of 2h 58m 44s.

So to get a time *span* of 3h 58m 44s encoded in a java.sql.Time, you have to make up for the time zone offset manually. You do that by parsing the time string "00:00:00" with java.sql.Time, which will result in an internal value of `-3600000` which is equivalent to 31 Dec 1969 23:00:00 GMT, i.e. one hour before the epoch. This is the negative of the time zone offset.

```
public static Date mergeDate(Date date, Time time) {
    long tzoffset = -(Time.valueOf("00:00:00").getTime());
    return new Date(date.getTime() + time.getTime() + tzoffset);
}
```

Of course, all this is a dirty hack, which is necessary because you insist on interpreting the Time's value as a time span, while it really is a point in time.

Comment: I cannot think of a better way to "merge" a DATE (with no "time" information) with an Sql Time (with no "date" information). I need to compare dates, and one of the sources is an SQL table that gives me a DATE and a TIME that i must put together.

Answer (score 2):

Instead, you can use this.

```
   public static Date getDate(Date date, Time time) {
        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, (int) time.getTime());
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, it works, But i get one hour less. Tue May 10 00:00:00 BST 2011 & 03:58:44 = Tue May 10 02:58:44 BST 2011

Comment: That is because you need to set the timezone properly. use setTimezone() method of the calendar.

Comment: I'm confused... java.util.date does not hold the timezone?

Answer (score 1):

Can you do

```
java.util.Date newDate = new java.util.Date(sqlDate.getTime());
```

Comment: That was my first try... it returns: Thu Jan 01 03:59:26 GMT 1970 :-\ So, the TIME is ok, but resets all other fields.

Comment: java.sql.Time **is a** java.util.Date ;-)

Answer (score 1):

try these

```
 public static Date getDate(Date date, Time time) {
            Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            Calendar calendar1=Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar1.setTime(time);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar1.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, calendar1.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            return calendar.getTime();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. If you cannot avoid getting the date as a `java.util.Date` (a class that doesn’t represent a date) and your time of day as a `java.sql.Time`, convert both to modern types and combine them from there.

### Java 8 and later

```
    // Time zone to use throughout
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    
    // Initialize values to be used for demonstration
    Instant startOfDay = LocalDate.of(2011, Month.MAY, 10)
            .atStartOfDay(zone)
            .toInstant();
    Date date = Date.from(startOfDay);
    Time time = Time.valueOf(LocalTime.of(3, 58, 44));
    
    // Do work
    LocalTime localTime = time.toLocalTime();
    LocalDateTime combination = date.toInstant()
            .atZone(zone)
            .toLocalDate()
            .atTime(localTime);
    
    // Print result
    System.out.println(combination);
```

Output:

> 2011-05-10T03:58:44

Only if you indispensably need a `Date`, typically for a legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade to java.time just now, convert back:

```
    Instant inZone = combination.atZone(zone).toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(inZone);
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

In my time zone the output is:

> Tue May 10 03:58:44 CEST 2011

### Java 6 and 7

For Java 6 and 7 use the backport of java.time, ThreeTen Backport (links at the botton). For the backport we need to use `DateTimeUtils` for converting to modern types:

```
    LocalTime localTime = DateTimeUtils.toLocalTime(time);
    LocalDateTime combination = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(date)
            .atZone(zone)
            .toLocalDate()
            .atTime(localTime);
```

Output is the same as before. Also if you need to convert back to a `Date`, use `DateTimeUtils`:

```
    Instant inZone = combination.atZone(zone).toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDate = DateTimeUtils.toDate(inZone);
```

Again output is the same as before.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.