# Java: java.util.date cannot be cast to java.sql.Time

Tags: java, sql, time, insert

I have time converted from millis and now i would like to make an SQL Insert with that time value. I tried this but it is not working:

```
        String INSERT_RECORD ="INSERT INTO PRAVIDLA (CAS,DEN,MIESTNOST,STAV) values(?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_RECORD);

        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));       
        calendar1.setTimeInMillis(milli);
        Time Cas2 = (Time) calendar1.getTime();

        pstmt.setTime(1, Cas2);
        pstmt.setInt(2, DEN);
        pstmt.setString(3, MIESTNOST);
        pstmt.setString(4, STAV);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: You can't just cast different types like that. Use the fields of `Date` to create a new `Time`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis have you worked with `java.sql.Time` before? Because there's no `java.util.Date` argument to pass to its constructor.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950806/merge-java-util-date-with-java-sql-time

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Can't you use the constructor `Time(long time)` with `Date#getTime()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is what I did when I had a similar problem.

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date("mm/dd/yyyy");
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Substitute a real date for "mm/dd/yyyy"

Answer (score 9):

`java.sql.Time` extends `java.util.Date`, so you cannot simply cast it.

You can try something like this:

```
Time time = new Time(date.getTime());
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Fixed, now using another constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`calendar1.getTime()` returns a `Date` object, and `Time` is a sub-class of `Date`, so a `Date` cannot be cast into a `Time`. You can try this instead:

```
Time Cas2 = new Time(calendar1.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Time extends java.util.Date
```

It is not possible to cast `Date` to `Time`.

You can use this instead:

```
Time time = new Time(date.getTime())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.  I've not tested the code.

```
Time time = new Time(calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) 
            + calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET));
```

You might have to subtract the zone offset.